# Visual C++: Compare Dates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, date, time

So I'm trying to find out if the current date on a Windows machine is after a hardcoded date. How would I go about doing this without using Boost or ATL? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform independent way to get the current date in C++ is `time(NULL)`, which returns seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  You can use other routines in [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) to either turn that into a string, pull out day/month/year/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OS-provided [`GetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions, which return date components, or [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601.  No additional support libraries needed.